# How to install Google Inc. add-ons (dl-ssl.google.com) (Third party add-ons) for use with google maps external library?

Tags: android, sdk, maps, android-mapview

I want to use com.google.android.maps.MapView, but can't figure out how to download the library for this. I have been looking at http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html. But in my SDK manager I simply can't find the section "third party add-ons" or the "google inc. add-ons (dl-ssl.google.com).

I am using eclipse and have updated the SDK manager, I've also updated everything within the SDK manager. Here's a screenshot of my SDK manager: http://cl.ly/1C1n141T2b351c0T1T3T

I've been googling around this for several hours now, but I seem to only find old links about this topic and none of them solves my issue. I would really appreciate an answer to how I can download the add-on so that I can create a mapview in my Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Google Maps package in the wrong place -- it's not under add-ons, but instead under each API level branch as part of the Google APIs. Here is what you have to do to get Google Maps in your app.

In the SDK manager, open up the branch corresponding to the API level you want to use [e.g. Android 2.3.3 (API 10)]. Under that branch, there is a 'Google APIs by Google Inc.' entry. Make sure that is checked along with 'SDK Platform' for that branch, and press Install. Wait for the SDK changes to complete.

Switch to your Eclipse project or create a new project, and link against the Google APIs for your desired API level (e.g. Google APIs, Google Inc, 2.3.3, 10).

You will also have to add an entry to the manifest to make sure that the library is referenced in your project. Within the application tag in the manifest, make sure you have

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your instructions was very helpfull and made me solve my issue! :) First I forgot to switch from Android to Google API under build target. Right click on the project -> Android and change build target from Android to Google API. But now everything works I think.

Comment: I had somehow got two different sdk's installed. I found out by checking the path under Mac: "Eclipse > Preferences... > Android > SDK Location" (Windows: "Window > Preferences... > Android > SDK Location") is correct. By referring the correct I solved the problem. Thanks for the help Theo